# distribution from percentage with R

Tags: r, distribution, percentage

I have distribution of parameter (natural gas mixture composition) expressed in percents. How to test such data for distribution parameters (it should be gamma, normal or lognormal distribution) and generate random composition based on that parameters in R?

Comment: when you say "mixture composition" do you mean you have a single measurement per observation (e.g. your data are a single vector of numbers, e.g. 21.2%, 3.2%, 46.7%, 54.1% ...), or do you have fractions of different components that sum to 1 for each observation ((2.5%, 90%, 7.5%), (10%, 90%, 0%), ... ) ?

Comment: Thank you, I should do analysis for one sample (composition), i.e. I'll have fractions of components that sum to 1 for each observation (sample). I should be able to test distribution of components in each sample (composition) separately.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a better question for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), but:

- it is *not* generally a good idea to choose from among a range of possible distributions according to goodness of fit. Instead, you should choose according to the *qualitative* characteristics of your data, something like this:

[image: distributions]

Frustratingly, this chart doesn't actually have the best choice for your data (composition, continuous, bounded between 0 and 1 [or 0 and 100]), which is a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) (although there are technical issues if you have values of exactly 0 or 100 in your sample).

In R:

```
## some arbitrary data
z <- c(2,8,40,45,56,58,70,89)
## fit (beta values must be in (0,1), not (0,100), so divide by 100)
(m <- MASS::fitdistr(z/100,"beta",start=list(shape1=1,shape2=1)))
## sample 1000 new values
z_new <- 100*rbeta(n=1000,shape1=m$estimate["shape1"],
                   shape2=m$estimate["shape2"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your example very much. However, it's related to thermodynamical analysis of plus fraction of complex hydrocarbon mixtures (such as oil composition). In practice, to estimate the fraction of components that is impossible to analyze in lab, gamma distribution is used. So the vector z in your example should have the sum of its elements equal to 100 (or 1). However, I'm not so good in R syntax to say if your example is applicable to gamma (or similar) distribution...